# Can I have a bit that references another part of a C bitfield?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I am trying to come up with a code snippet where a property of a struct references a particular bit in another property of the same struct. This would look something like:

```
struct A {
    unsigned char type;
    unsigned char is_family_a : 1;  // should reference bit 7 of above somehow
};

struct A example;
example.type = 0x17;
printf("%i\n", example.is_family_a);  // 0
example.type = 0xF7;
printf("%i\n", example.is_family_a);  // 1
```

I looked at the cppreference page for it and didn't see anything. I also looked around stackoverflow, but didn't really find anything. This does seem to work if I use macros, but I think the compiler is likely to optimize this sort of thing better than I can.

Comment: `union` perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
struct A {
    union {
        unsigned char type;
        struct {
            unsigned char : 7;  // remove for big endian
            unsigned char is_family_a : 1;  // should reference bit 7 of above somehow
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: Nice answer. It may be helpful to explain a little bit, the OP maybe does not know ´union´ well yet.

Comment: Sweet! I didn't even think of using union here. Thank you!